# R Vectorization: How to return the index of the first element of each row in a matrix that meets a condition and sum all elements until that index?

Tags: r, mapply

I am looking for a vectorized solution. Say I generate 100 samples of 10 draws with replacement. Next, I want to find the first index of the first element of a matrix of cumulative sums that means some condition, say, >=10. Then, I want to sum all elements of each row up until the index of the first element meeting that condition. MWE:

```
set <- c(1, 5, 7, 13, 15, 17)
samp <- samp <- matrix(sample(set, size = 100*10, replace = TRUE), nrow=simCount) # generate 100 samples of 10 draws
b <- matrix(apply(samp, 1, cumsum), 
  nrow = 100, byrow=TRUE) >= 10 # compare each element with 10, return boolean
```

I'm not sure how to use `apply` with `which(x)=="TRUE"`. I tried a few variations but I'm not sure how code it correctly.

After I get that, I'll be able to use `apply(b, 1, min)` to return the first element (minimum index) for each row that is >=10.

Comment: There is a typo in your MWE. Please fix.

Comment: @Pascal fixed, thanks

Comment: First your sample with `rep` is incorrect according to the description. Maybe use: `samp <- matrix(sample(c(seq(1,5,1)), size = 1000, replace = TRUE), nrow=100)`

Comment: @N8TRO Good catch, thanks! Definitely don't want to keep repeating my draws. Fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `b` portion makes sense, but I added it to the answer just to be thorough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set seed please for "random" examples:

```
set.seed(111)
samp <- matrix(sample(1:5, s=1000, r=T), nrow=100)
(answer1 <- samp[which(apply(samp,1,function(x)sum(x)>30)),1])
# [1] 4 3 3 3 1 1 3 5 2 4 2 5 4 2 4 1 3 2 4 4 5 4 2 4 5 5 4 5 3 3 1 1 2 1 4 3 4 5
#[39] 1 5 1 4 4 3 3 2 5 5
```

Explanation:

`apply(samp,1, function(x) sum(x) > 30)`
Well, if you add 10 positive integers, `>=10` will ALWAYS be true.
apply to "samp" for each row this function.

`which(x)` returns the index of all TRUE values of x. (the rows of interest)

`samp[`(rows returned by which)`,` (`1`)st column`]` ... basic indexing

unwrap step by step from the outside in for better understanding.

```
b <- matrix(apply(samp, 1, cumsum), nrow=100, byrow=T)>=10
apply(b,1,function(x)which(x)[1])
#  [1] 4 5 4 3 3 5 3 4 3 4 3 3 5 4 5 4 2 4 3 6 3 3 5 4 3 3 2 4 4 6 3 4 3 4 5 4 4
# [38] 4 3 5 3 6 3 3 5 5 3 3 4 6 4 5 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 5 3 4 3 4 4 3 4 6 3 5 4 4 4 4
# [75] 3 3 5 4 4 3 3 4 4 5 4 4 4 3 4 3 5 4 3 5 3 6 4 5 5 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: How do I sum up the elements of each row up until the indices found above in a vectorized fashion?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rowCumsums` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
apply(rowCumsums(samp)>=10, 1, which.max)
```